# Inherited class casting

Tags: c#, casting

I have this base class:

```
namespace DynamicGunsGallery
{
    public class Module
    {
        protected string name;

        public virtual string GetName() { return name; }
        public virtual string GetInfo() { return null;  }
    }
}
```

And Im creating dynamic libraries that inherit from base class, e.g. (AK47.dll)

```
namespace DynamicGunsGallery
{
    public class AK47 : Module
    {
        public AK47() { name = "AK47";  }

        public override string GetInfo()
        { 
            return @"The AK-47 is a selective-fire, gas-operated 7.62×39mm assault rifle, first developed in the USSR by Mikhail Kalashnikov.
                    It is officially known as Avtomat Kalashnikova . It is also known as a Kalashnikov, an AK, or in Russian slang, Kalash.";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm loading dynamic libraries using this ([inspired by this link](http://www.michael-clarke-blog.com/2010/08/c-dynamic-class-loading/comment-page-1/#comment-6340)):

```
namespace DynamicGunsGallery
{
    public static class ModulesManager
    {
        public static Module getInstance(String fileName)
        {
            /* Load in the assembly. */
            Assembly moduleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(fileName);

            /* Get the types of classes that are in this assembly. */
            Type[] types = moduleAssembly.GetTypes();

            /* Loop through the types in the assembly until we find
             * a class that implements a Module.
             */
            foreach (Type type in types)
            {
                if (type.BaseType.FullName == "DynamicGunsGallery.Module")
                {
                    //
                    // Exception throwing on next line !
                    //
                    return (Module)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I have included base class in both, my executable which contains ModuleManager and in dll library. I have no problem when compiling, but when I run this code I get an error:

> **InvalidCastException** was unhandled.
>
> *Unable to cast object of type DynamicGunsGallery.AK47 to type
>   DynamicGunsGallery.Module*

So the question is: **Why cant I cast derivated class to base class?**

Is there other way to load dynamic library and "control" it using methods from base class?

Comment: Is it possible you have the `Module` class declared twice, i.e. in the main program as well as in the `AK47.dll`? You should replace the type name string comparison with a `typeof(Module).IsAssignableFrom(type)` call.

Comment: Yes, I have declared `Module` in main program and library. I have it in main program because I want to use its methods to control libraries, so I guess main program (compilator) must know its declarations. And I have it in library, because every library will derive from it, so I guess again, compilator have to know its declarations to be able to compile derivative. Am I wrong? ... I used string comparison because `typeof()` doesnt work to me.

Comment: Also, try splitting out your final line such that: `object something =activator.createinstance` and then `return (module)something`. Set a breakpoint and make sure that something is the type you were expecting?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. In your sub library, you can't re-declare module; you must reference the module from the original library. Add a reference to the main project from the project which has ak class in it. I'd also think about changing the namespaces to make it obvious that you've got two libraries going on

Comment: Just because two classes (defined in different assemblies) have the same name, they don't somehow magically unite and become one and the same class. It is unclear to me why you want to do this dynamically. Can't `AK47.dll` be compiled with a reference to the DLL of the main program?

Comment: I'm learning to create plugin ability to my program. I want users to be able to create own plugins and use them, without having to recompile the main program :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going from your comments:

In your sub library, you can't re-declare module; you must reference the module from the original library.

Add a reference to the main project from the project which has ak class in it.

I'd also think about changing the namespaces to make it obvious that you've got two libraries going on

Comment: Thank you :) ... even `typeof().IsAssignableFrom()` works now ... Yes I will change namespacess too :)